# Scrollview memory leak pagination

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiscrollview, pagination

I have around 700 to 800 images to load in Scrollview (Vertical) like below. (single row single column).

```
         Y
       X|_|
       X|_|
       X|_|
       X|_|
       X|_|
       X|_|
       X|_|
```

per scroll I can pull 12 images via web service call and display in my App.. I am using SDWebCache also. As I am not removing any loaded images unless the viewWillDisappear , I am getting Memory warning after 200 images. I wish to implement vertical Pagination, also I wanna handle memory effectively by removing images appropriately. I wanna keep previous , current and next Scroll images (means 36 images) rest of others , need to remove from view (RAM). But , I am not sure how can I reload after I removed images from view. If you guys need code , I will give. But I wish to know any easy implementation methodology for this case. Thank you

Comment: You will use UITableView to reuse cell instead of UIScrollView.

Comment: Yes in this case UITableView is the best, so you does not need to manage it, like 36 images.

Comment: Either implement reusability of imageviews in your scrollview or else use mechanism which already provides it like `UITableView`, `UICollectionView`.

Comment: but , As this view controller has many views interconnected and now reworking isn't possible. But I will try for sure. Any quick fix for this issue in Scroll view itself ??